# Ext js Editor Grid Disable Multiple Row Selection

Tags: extjs

my grid allowing to select multiple row selection that is once i click on cell and press shift+arrow down button it allows me to select next set of records i wanted to disable this functionality how it can be done,on grid level how to catch keypress events and return false once shift+arrow down button is pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ExtJS 3.x add this to the grid properties:

`selModel: new Ext.grid.rowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true})`

Comment: this seems like a very old version of extjs. I'm using v4.2. The solution for extjs4 seems to be selModel: new Ext.selection.Model({mode: 'SINGLE'})

Comment: Yes, it's ExtJS 3.x. Still in extensive use.

Answer (score 2):

Grids behave as you want by default. Make sure you have *NOT* set `multiSelect` or `simpleSelect` to true.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's hard to understand your question without any punctuation. Secondly, without any code example, it's even harder to understand a question without any punctuations.

Here's my guess answer of your question:

```
editorgridpanel.on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey === true && e.getKey() === e.DOWN) {
        e.stopEvent(); //this will stop the shift+down keypress event from proceeding.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems to be a bit out of date. For version ExtJS4.x use this solution :

```
selModel: new Ext.selection.Model({mode: 'SINGLE'})
```

Or just use this :

```
selModel: {mode: 'SINGLE'}
```