# Disable Multi-Row selecton in ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

There is already a similar question in SO to my quesiton :

[Ext js Editor Grid Disable Multiple Row Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289459/ext-js-editor-grid-disable-multiple-row-selection)

But the accepted answer is wrong. It says to use **RowSelectionModel** as a property like so :

```
selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
```

But in the API no such thing exists (maybe they are talking about a different extjs version).

How can you disable multi selection in Extjs grids? ie. No SHIFT or CTRL multi select. Only single selections are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)

It shows that you can specify the selection model like so:

> Grids use a Row Selection Model by default, but this is easy to customise like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    store: ...
});
```

Or the alternative option would be:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    store: ...
});
```

EDIT:

You need to specify the [Selection Model MODE](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-cfg-mode)

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kd0)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'items'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        });


        Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel({
                mode: "SINGLE"
            }),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: this does not answer my question. I am trying to disable multiple row selection with SHIFT or CTRL